# Check current user after a credentials change from another device

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Here's the thing: I'm developping an android app with a website version (for non-android users) with Firebase and Firebase-auth. I would like to make a user able to reset his password and be sure that he's automatically signed out right after a password reset/change on my android and web app. Firebase auth doc says, about users lifecycle (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/users):

> The user changes their password: Firebase issues new access and refresh tokens and renders the old tokens expired. This automatically expires the user's token and/or signs out the user on every device, for security reasons.

After reading that, my first naive thought was "OK, so it seems that I only have to check the current user"

I've tried the following:

1. Send password reset email, reset password then change password (from a web browser)
2. Restart android app
3. Check current user :

```
FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null)
{ ... }
```

Doing so, `getCurrentUser()` still returns a non-null user.

(There's no listeners registered to my FirebaseAuth instance yet)

Is there anything I missed implementing or I didn't understood? Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: How long did you wait after changing the password?  I'd expect it to take an hour for the client SDK to attempt another refresh.

Comment: I've waited a whole night, the function still returns a non-null user